# How to read Scikit-Learn source code?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am learning to use scikit-learn to build a decision tree. However, when I go with the example code. I found the kernel code of the tree building is empty.

I am using the following code:

```
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = [0, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

I go to fit() method to see the details of the code. And I think the most important code for implementing decision tree is the following code at line 362 of the tree.py.

```
 builder.build(self.tree_, X, y, sample_weight, X_idx_sorted)
```

However, when I go into the build method in _tree.py, I found that all method is empty which only contains 'pass' keyword, such as:

```
""" Build a decision tree in depth-first fashion. """
def build(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Build a decision tree from the training set (X, y). """
    pass
```

I am wondering about the strange code. I have no idea to figure it out. Am I wrong about the source code? How could this code run?

I am using PyCharm as my IDE and using Anaconda3 as my environment....It was so strange

Comment: Not sure where you're looking, but this is (one of) the implementation: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L145

Comment: I am using PyCharm as my IDE and using Anaconda3 as my environment....It was so strange

Comment: Oh I get it now. Sometimes the IDE uses some python stub functions for cython. The syntax checker needs that to work properly I guess (or something like that)

Comment: Some parts of scikit-learn use Cython code for faster execution, like tree module, then svm module and so. This is not actually the proper python def and class the IDE may be looking for.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar Thx. Maybe I should not check it by PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the libraries in sklearn are compiled with cython.
And you can't find the source code in your folder.
They are placed in your folder as a form of .pyd and it is impossible to read this.
The .pyd files are only imported from the other .py files like library.

You can find the original source code in sklern git repository as a form of .pyx. (file name is same)

The cython syntax is a little different from python syntax, especially in defining variables.
If you want to change the code, you should compile .pyx to .pyd.